# Is it possible to get the full timezone name in ruby?

Tags: ruby, timezone

I need to get the current timezone but `Time.now.zone` only has options for the abbreviation. Poked around in the docs and couldn't find anything useful. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think this functionality is built into the ruby language. If you are using rails you could call `Time.zone.name` however.

Comment: What OS are you using?  On Win, I see that it returns full name; on Ubuntu, it's abbreviated.

Comment: @orde ah yeah that's what it is I'm on Ubuntu. I think at this point it's easiest to just make a mapping of gmt offset --> full name.

Comment: No, you cannot make that mapping.  See "time zone != offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `Time.now.getlocal.zone`. This should work.

Comment: Still returning the abbreviation unfortunately :/

Comment: @Niko maybe try Time.zone.name?